# Python determine if list is sorted using predicated filter

Tags: python, list, filter, predicate

So I am trying to import and copy a list.  Both lists are then read left to rightwith list2 starting at index[1:]

From there both lists are compared each iteration to determine if list2 is greater than list1.

Also I am aware that this is probably the least efficient way to go about this, but the assignment requires it be a predicated filter.

This is what I have so far.

```
def main():
    fileName = input("Enter file name: ")
    dataSet1 = open(fileName, 'r')
    dataSet2 = dataSet1.copy()
    isSorted(dataSet1, dataSet2)


def isSorted(i, j): return i <= j
for i, j in range():
    list(filter(isSorted(i, j)))
```

What it is supposed to do:

If all iterations in List2 are greater than List1 it should return True, else False.

Error I'm Getting:
in module
for i, j, in range():
range expected at least 1 argument, got 0

Naturally I have tried adding arguments to range(), and watch my syntax errors multiply.

Comment: "Naturally I have tried adding arguments to range()". That's the solution to your problem. New errors after that change were either caused by introducing a new syntax error while passing a number, or they are unrelated errors that would have shown anyways. Also note, `dataSet2 = dataSet1` does not create a copy. That's two references to the same list.

Comment: Thanks, fixed the list issue with .copy().  Still working on the rest.

Answer (score 0):

`range` obviously requires an input (at least one), and you should understand the meaning of `range`, which generates numbers from `start` to `stop` with a `step`-size of choice. Not inputting a necessary input is wrong even if that means you have "less" errors.

So - fix this bug, and then go on to the next error and fix that as well.
(Specifically - `i < j[1:]` probably gives an error, because comparing these two makes no sense, and probably some other problems...).